# Python type equality

Tags: python, types

I am reading from an Oracle database and would like to check if the field is column is of type `cx_Oracle.DATETIME`.

I have tried the following:

`if columnTypes[columnIndex] == cx_Oracle.DATETIME:`

and

`if columnTypes[columnIndex] is cx_Oracle.DATETIME:`

Neither work.

If I do:

`print columnTypes[columnIndex]`

it returns:

`<type 'cx_Oracle.DATETIME'>`

**EDIT:**

It worked by storing the type in a variable:

`dbDateType = cx_Oracle.DATETIME`

and

`if columnTypes[columnIndex] == dbDateType`

Comment: Does `issubclass()` work?

Comment: What happens if you `print cx_Oracle.DATETIME`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters no, it doesn't.

Comment: @kojiro `<type 'cx_Oracle.DATETIME'>`

Comment: repr madness. Maybe it's like JavaScript NaN, that isn't even equal to itself? (j/k) Sanity check: What happens if you do `if columnTypes[columnIndex] != cx_Oracle.DATETIME: print columnTypes[columnIndex], cx_Oracle.DATETIME`?

Answer (score 2):

The best way is probably to do:

```
isinstance(columnTypes[columnIndex], cx_Oracle.DATETIME)
```

If you want to check for exact type, `type(obj) == myType` woudl work, but using `isinstance` allows for sub-typing.

Comment: I had already tried this, but I didn't put it in the question, because `columnTypes[columnIndex]` is not an instance, its a type.

Comment: I think you have the arguments reversed. It seems to me `columnTypes` is a list of actual *types*, and `cx_Oracle.DATETIME` would be the object that is an instance of that type.

Comment: @kojiro is `cx_Oracle.DATETIME` not a type itself?

Comment: @Ben well, its `str` or `unicode` certainly wants you to think it is. It probably is, but that wasn't obvious from the start.

Comment: @Ben `cx_Oracle.DATETIME` is an instance of a `cx_Oracle.DATETIME` object. Confusing, but that means it's a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Answer (score 2):

Does the column `columnTypes` store the types themselves or representations of the types as for instance a string or `type` instance?

Try getting the output of both `columnTypes[columnIndex]` and `type(columnTypes[columnIndex])`. Hopefully one will give you `<type 'cx_Oracle.DATETIME'>`, which you can then compare to `type(cx_Oracle.DATETIME)`.

If you get a super/subclass you will have to use `isinstance` in a similar fashion - [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/differences-between-isinstance-and-type-in-python) might be of interest.